# ZeroMQ: have to sleep before send

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm write a zeromq demo with Forwarder device (with pyzmq)

Here are the codes(reference to https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/devices/forwarder.html ):

forwarder.py

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
frontend = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
frontend.bind('tcp://*:5559')
frontend.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

backend = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
backend.bind('tcp://*:5560')

zmq.device(zmq.FORWARDER, frontend, backend)
```

sub.py

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5560')
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

while True:
    print socket.recv()
```

pub.py

```
import zmq, time

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5559')
# time.sleep(0.01)
socket.send('9 hahah')
```

I run `python forwarder.py`, `python sub.py` in the terminal

then run `python pub.py`, the subscriber can't get the message. However, if I sleep a little time(for example 0.01s) before send, it works.

So my problem is, why have I `sleep` before send? thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's known as [Slow Joiner](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter5/) syndrome. Read the [guide](https://zguide.zeromq.org/), there are ways to avoid it using [Node Coordination](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#Node-Coordination).

Comment: specifically, look at the [pub-sub synchronization example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Node-Coordination) to see it working. As the figure shows, you'll use an additional REP/REQ pair of sockets to sync your [pub](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:syncpub) and [sub](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:syncsub) sockets.

Comment: It also says, that the example it shows has an unrobust 1 second delay in the subscriber, and then suggests you basically need to send bogus data from the publisher to the subscriber until everything is flushed through. Look at the "more robust model" blurb at the very end.

Comment: Everything is 404.

Comment: looks like it moved [here](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#Node-Coordination).